# Cannot write video in OpenCV from ip camera

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, ip-camera, video-codecs

I am using IP webcam and collecting video from my phone camera. The issue I am facing is my code does not write any video. It perfectly shows me the video stream but I get only 1kb file of video. I am using python 3.10, opencv 4.9 and windows 11 Home
Here's my code-

```
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', codec, 20.0, (640, 480))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://IP:PORT/video')
......
cv2.imshow("Video", final_image)
output.write(final_image)
```

I tried different combination of codecs(mp4v, XVID, H264) and video format(mp4, avi, mkv). I also tried with a recorded video from my local file. But my code does not write the video. Still I only get one kb file. In some cases I get this in my log too-`[mjpeg @ 00000244989c2340] overread 8`.

The shape of the `final_image` is `(1280, 720, 3)`.

Comment: What if you put this `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://IP:PORT/video')` before  codec = `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`?

Comment: What is the shape of `final_image`?

Comment: @DanMašek The shape of the final image is (1280, 720, 3)

Comment: @toyotaSupra Tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Well, there's your problem. When creating the `VideoWriter` you state that the size of the images will be 640x480, and then you start feeding in 720x1280 size images. Since the size doesn't match, all that invalid input is just discarded.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you, I needed to resize the final image. This worked

Comment: Right, that's a possibility, but keep in mind that 640x480 is in landscape orientation and has aspect ratio of 4:3 and 720x1280 is in portrait orientation and even if correctly oriented would have aspect ratio of 16:9. Even with both images in same orientation there would be a distortion due to the resize, and with the orientation being different, it will be rather extreme. Hence, if you want to keep the output video resolution as is, you may need to do some pillarboxing after a resize to avoid distorting the aspect ratio.